# pass arguments from shell script to java code

Tags: java, shell, scripting, arguments

I am trying to pass two arguments from shell script to java code.

```
java -classpath *various properties* -Xmx1025m MainClass "$Arg1" "$Arg2"
```

However, the application is exiting immediately from which I inferred that the arguments are not getting passed to java code.

The application is working fine when I test it in my eclipse using command line args, but when I invoke it from script, its failing. I even printed out the arg1, arg2 values before invoking the java command, they seem to be okay.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right.

Get your Java program to start by looping through its arguments and printing them out, to confirm; but the command line is right. You could show the whole script if you'd like more detailed help.

Comment: should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm sorry, I cannot post the script here due to security reasons. I am printing out the command line arguments in my java code immediately in the main function. But the process is terminating even before it.

Comment: @JunedAhsan No it shouldn't. The answer to OP's question is that he is correctly passing the arguments.

Comment: It sounds as though your Java program isn't getting executed at all, in that case. Have you tried running it from the command line? Do you get an error? Are you sure the class path is correct?